# Warning: type of ‘numRest’ defaults to ‘int’ (in function 'sleep')

Tags: c, syntax, gcc-warning, function-declaration

I get a warning In function ‘sleep’: warning: type of ‘numRest’ defaults to ‘int’ and I have no idea why. It runs perfectly fine but apparently I got this warning. Does anyone else get this warning when they run it?

```
void sleep(numRest){

if ((numRest >= 0) && (numRest <=4)){
    printf("Sleep deprived!");
}


else if ((numRest > 4) && (numRest < 6)){
    printf("You need more sleep.");
}


else if ((numRest >= 6) && (numRest < 8)){
    printf("Not quite enough.");
}


else{
    printf("Well done!");
}

return;
}

int main()
{
int numSleep = -1;


if (numSleep == -1){
    printf("Test 1\n");
    printf("Input: -1\n");
    printf("Expected Result: Error, you cannot have a negative number of hours of sleep.\n");
    printf("Actual Result: ");
    sleep(numSleep);
    printf("\n\n");

    numSleep = 4.5;
    printf("Test 2\n");
    printf("Input: 4.5\n");
    printf("Expected Result: You need more sleep.\n");
    printf("Actual Result: ");
    sleep(numSleep);
    printf("\n\n");


}





return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is with the function signature definition.

```
 void sleep(numRest) {
```

should be

```
void sleep(int numRest) {
```

Otherwise, the compiler will "assume" (*now obsolete by latest standard*) that the missing datatype is `int`.

Related, quoting from `C11`, Major changes (over previous versions) list

> - remove implicit `int`

That said,

- `sleep()` is a [library function already](https://linux.die.net/man/3/sleep), prototyped in `unistd.h`, **do not** try to use the same for for user-defined functions.
- `int main()` should be `int main(void)`, at least for hosted environments to conform to the standard.

Answer (score 1):

You have to explicitly put variable type in function declaration as:

```
void sleep(int numRest) {

//your code here

}
```